# Trouble using functions

Tags: python, function

I have fixed the typo and i am still having issues trying to get the program to correctly raise a ValueError. This is my code;

```
def grade(mark):
    if not isinstance(mark, int):
        raise TypeError ("Invalid input, please enter an integer")
    if mark != range (0, 101):
        raise ValueError ("Invalid input, Please enter an integer between 0 
and 101")
    if mark >= 60:
        return "D"
    elif mark >= 50:
        return "M"
    elif mark >= 40:
        return "P"
    else:
        return "F"
print (grade(mark=int(input("Please enter the students mark: "))))
```

This is what the console returns;

```
J:\Python\python.exe K:/Jetbrains/.PyCharmCE/config/scratches/scratch_21.py
Please enter the students mark: 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:/Jetbrains/.PyCharmCE/config/scratches/scratch_21.py", line 19, in 
<module>
print (grade(mark=int(input("Please enter the students mark: "))))
File "K:/Jetbrains/.PyCharmCE/config/scratches/scratch_21.py", line 10, in 
grade
raise ValueError ("Invalid input, Please enter an integer between 0 and 
101")
ValueError: Invalid input, Please enter an integer between 0 and 101

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: you swapped the order of `input` and `int`

Comment: make it be `int(input("Please enter the student\'s mark: "))` instead of `input(int("..."))`

Comment: it wouldn't let me input any data it would just print that to console as soon as i click run

Comment: i swapped them around and though it doesn't any errors nothing it printed to the console

Comment: you also have to `print` the result of `grade`

Comment: why should something be printed to the console if there is no statement that "prints" to the console in this code?

Comment: `return` causes a function to end execution and provide the caller with a result (which will default to `None` if one isn't supplied). `print` sends character data to the console to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this line apart:

```
grade(mark=input(int("Please enter the student's mark: ")))
```

We can re-write it as:

```
query_text = "Please enter the student's mark: "
number = int(query_text)
input_from_user = input(number)
grade(mark=input_from_user)
```

Looking at the second and third lines, this is probably not what you want.  Why would you want to convert `query_text` to an `int` *before* you get input from the user?  What you would rather see is:

```
query_text = "Please enter the student's mark: "
input_from_user = input(query_text)
number = int(input_from_user)
grade(mark=number)
```

That gets re-written to one line as:

```
grade(mark=int(input("Please enter the student's mark: ")))
```

---

One piece of advice:

You are trying to convert the user input into an `int` *before* you pass it into the `grade()` function.  That's not necessarily a bad idea, but your check for an int happens inside the `grade()` function.  As a result, a bad user input would not get caught in the `grade()` function, as is your intent.

A better way to write the check in the `grade()` function would be to do this:

```
def grade(mark):
    try:
        mark = int(mark)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Invalid input, please enter an integer.")
    if mark >= 60:
        return "D"
    .
    .
    .
```

It might not seem much different, but now you can pass in an `int` or a `str`, as long as it can successfully be converted to an `int`.  (And that's what you want, right?)

The call to grade can now be simplified to:

```
grade(mark=input("Please enter the student's mark: "))
```

and no `int` casting is needed in the call to `grade()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap int and input. Then you need to print the return output to console using print command

```
def grade(mark):
    if not isinstance(mark, int):
        raise ValueError ("Invalid input, please enter an integer")
    if mark >= 60:
        return "D"
    elif mark >= 50:
        return "M"
    elif mark >= 40:
        return "P"
    else:
        return "F"

print(grade(mark=int(input("Please enter the students mark: "))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch `input` with `int` and add a `print`.

New line:

```
print (grade(mark=int(input("Please enter the students mark: "))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add , you dont need to specify that `grade(mark=int(input()))` as you defined the function you also set that the first given parameter will be `mark`.